# Apache Thrift warning "No seqid to unset" (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, thrift, thrift-protocol

"[WARN] No seqid to unset"
What are the reasons for this warning? (NodeJS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was a version mismatch. 0.9.3 & latest

Answer (score 2):

for version 0.11.0, it's a bug

```
TBinaryProtocol.prototype.writeMessageEnd = function() {
    if (this._seqid) {
        this._seqid = null;
    } else {
        log.warning('No seqid to unset');
    }
};
```

this._seqid would false when it is 0.

It's now fixed in branch master

```
// from `if (this._seqid)` to `if (this._seqid !== null )`
TBinaryProtocol.prototype.writeMessageEnd = function() {
    if (this._seqid !== null) {
        this._seqid = null;
    } else {
        log.warning('No seqid to unset');
    }
};
```

see source file : https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/binary_protocol.js